# How to change material on a gameobject by rotation?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mesh, gameobject

I want to change between 2 materials, depending on the platforms (gameobject) rotation.
Here is what I've done so far:

```
public class PlatformSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject platform;
    public Material[] platformMaterial;
    Material currentMaterial;
    Renderer _renderer;
}

    void Start()
    {
        _renderer = this.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    }
```

I also wrote this, but I don't want to change materials by buttons:

```
    public void LeftTurn()
    {
        _renderer.material = platformMaterial[0];
        currentMaterial = _renderer.material;
    }
    public void RightTurn()
    {
        _renderer.material = platformMaterial[1];
        currentMaterial = _renderer.material;
    }
}
```

And this is where the platform rotates randomly 90 degrees to the left or to the right:

```
    public struct SpawnPoint
    {
        public Vector3 position;
        public Quaternion orientation;

        public void Step(float distance)
        {
            if (Random.value < 0.5)
            {
                position.x += distance;
                orientation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0); //change to one of the materials
            }
            else
            {
                position.z += distance;
                orientation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0); //change to the other of the materials.
             //This is where I want to material to switch.
             //When the objects position changes, the material changes too.
            }
        }
    }
```

There is a picture of the gameplay. I want to change the material of all the corner platforms to have a nice curve line view.

[image: Picture]

Can anyone help me what and how to do in this case? I am a bit lost there.
Every help is highly appreciated!

EDIT: new code looks like that. The only issue is that Unity gives me 15 errors (see on the picture below), even if Visual Studio says no issue has been found. The errors refer to the switch.

```
public class PlatformSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject platform;
    public Transform lastPlatform;
    SpawnPoint _spawn;
    bool stop;

    public Material straightMaterial;
    public Material turnLeftMaterial;
    public Material turnRightMaterial;
    public Renderer roadPrefab;

    [System.Serializable]

    public struct SpawnPoint
    {
       public Vector3 position;
        public Quaternion orientation;
        public RoadType type;

        public enum RoadType
        {
            Straight,
            LeftTurn,
            RightTurn
        }

        private enum Direction
        {
            Z,
            X,
        }

        private Direction lastDirection;

        public void Step(float distance)
        {
            type = RoadType.Straight;

            if (Random.value < 0.5f)
            {
                position.x += distance;
                orientation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0);
                if (lastDirection == Direction.Z)
                {
                    type = RoadType.RightTurn;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                position.z += distance;
                orientation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
                if (lastDirection == Direction.X)
                {
                    type = RoadType.LeftTurn;
                }

                lastDirection = Direction.Z;
            }
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        _spawn.position = lastPlatform.position;
        _spawn.orientation = transform.rotation;

        StartCoroutine(SpawnPlatforms());
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnPlatforms()
    {
        while (!stop)
        {
            var _spawn = new SpawnPoint();

            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                var newPlatform = Instantiate(roadPrefab, _spawn.position, _spawn.orientation);

                _spawn.Step(1.5f);

                var roadMaterial = _spawn.type switch
                {
                    SpawnPoint.RoadType.LeftTurn => turnLeftMaterial,
                    SpawnPoint.RoadType.RightTurn => turnRightMaterial,
                    _ => straightMaterial
                };

                newPlatform.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = roadMaterial;

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. What is currently happening, and how is that different from what you would like to happen

Comment: Hey Jay, thank you for answering! Literally, nothing happens. I played around with that but no success so far. I attached a picture to the question to illustrate better what I actually want.

Comment: The code posted above does not produce the errors shown. Please edit the question to include a [mre].

Comment: Also, why do you have a for loop nested in your while loop, and also create a new spawn point at the start of each iteration of the while? Surely you would want to use `var _spawn = new SpawnPoint(); while(true){  var newPlatform /* ... */ yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f); }`

Comment: I tried everything already it is still a complete ***... Platforms getting generated all over the place with random materials. I gave up on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it sounds like you basically have a working system for switching the materials and spawning you road parts and materials already look correctly according to your rotations - now you only need to identify the curves.

Actually this is pretty simple:

- is the current part in X direction and the next will be in Z -> Left Turn
- is the current part in Z direction and the next will be in X -> RightTurn
- any other case is straight

So you could probably do something like

```
public struct SpawnPoint
{
    public Vector3 position;
    public Quaternion orientation;
    public RoadType type;

    public enum RoadType
    {
        Straight,
        LeftTurn,
        RightTurn
    }

    private enum Direction
    {
        // since your orientation by default equals the Z direction use that as default value for the first tile
        Z,
        X, 
    }
    private Direction lastDirection;

    public void Step(float distance)
    {
        type = RoadType.Straight;

        if (Random.value < 0.5f)
        {
            position.x += distance;
            orientation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0);

            if(lastDirection == Direction.Z)
            {
                type = RoadType.RightTurn;
            }

            lastDirection = Direction.X;
        }
        else
        {
            position.z += distance;
            orientation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0); 

            if(lastDirection == Direction.X)
            {
                type = RoadType.LeftTurn;
            }

            lastDirection = Direction.Z;
        }
    }
}
```

And you didn't show your spawn code but I would assume something like

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material straightMaterial;
    public Material turnLeftMaterial;
    public Material turnRightMaterial;

    public Renderer roadPrefab;

    private void Awake()
    {
        var spawnPoint = new SpawnPoint();
        
        for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            var roadTile = Instantiate(roadPrefab, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.orientation);

            // do the Step after spawning the current tile but before assigning the material
            // -> we want/need to know already where the next tile is going to be
            spawnPoint.Step(1f);
            
            var roadMaterial = spawnPoint.type switch
            {
                SpawnPoint.RoadType.LeftTurn => turnLeftMaterial,
                SpawnPoint.RoadType.RightTurn => turnRightMaterial,
                _ => straightMaterial
            };

            roadTile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = roadMaterial;
        }
    }
}
```

Behold my Paint skills ;)

[image]

Comment: Wow, you really put all the effort into that answer! Huge thanks to you! The only problem I can't solve in this code is the switch. Visual Studio has no problem with it but Unity gives me 15 errors for missing brackets and semicolons. I updated the code inside the question, maybe you see something I didn't.

Comment: @imbruceter you have a closing `}` after `_renderer;`

Comment: I decided to use a different switch, now it is working but it does something reaaaally strange :DDDD See: https://ibb.co/Y05NjVc

Comment: @imbruceter which Unity version are you using? It is possible that you have an older version that uses a c# version where the `switch` pattern matching was not yet supported. In that case you could change that part to `Material roadMaterial = null; switch(spawnPoint.type){ case SpawnPoint.RoadType.LeftTurn: roadMaterial = turnLeftMaterial; break; case SpawnPoint.RoadType.RightTurn: roadMaterial = turnRightMaterial; break; default: roadMaterial = straightMaterial; break; }`

Comment: I did the same exact thing, 100%. Something else causes the problem. The materials should change from the 4th platform, because I placed 3 platform prefab onto the scene to fill the camera view. Therefore have I made a public Transform lastPlatform, so platform generation starts only from the last played platform. But besides that, must be some other issue as well. I guess the materials do change in all type of angles but I cannot debug it.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you started using `Quaternion.Dot`.

[image]

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Renderer))]
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material Material1;
    public Material Material2;
    public Vector3 Euler = new(90, 0, 0);
    private Renderer _renderer;

    private void Start()
    {
        _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        _renderer.material = Material1;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        var dot = Quaternion.Dot(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(Euler));

        if (Mathf.Approximately(dot, 1.0f))
        {
            _renderer.material = Material2;
        }
        else
        {
            _renderer.material = Material1;
        }
    }
}
```

**Using different materials for N, E, S, W corners:**

[image]

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Renderer))]
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material Material1;
    public Material Material2;
    public Material Material3;
    public Material Material4;
    public Vector3 Euler1 = new(0, 0, 0);
    public Vector3 Euler2 = new(0, 90, 0);
    public Vector3 Euler3 = new(0, 180, 0);
    public Vector3 Euler4 = new(0, 270, 0);
    private Renderer _renderer;

    private void Start()
    {
        _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        _renderer.material = Material1;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Mathf.Approximately(Quaternion.Dot(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(Euler1)), 1.0f))
        {
            _renderer.material = Material1;
        }

        if (Mathf.Approximately(Quaternion.Dot(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(Euler2)), 1.0f))
        {
            _renderer.material = Material2;
        }

        if (Mathf.Approximately(Quaternion.Dot(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(Euler3)), 1.0f))
        {
            _renderer.material = Material3;
        }

        if (Mathf.Approximately(Quaternion.Dot(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(Euler4)), 1.0f))
        {
            _renderer.material = Material4;
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to wrap the rotation past 360 degrees, else it'll always look yellow (4th material).

Comment: This is awesome! Looks like it is gonna work. Can you please tell me one last thing? I was planning to do that in another way, attach new materials only for the corner platforms, but your method handles only two. Let me explain. There are 3 directions: left, right, straightforward. By this method, only left and right is attachable. See: https://postimg.cc/F78XnR8X Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Check my update with more corners.

Comment: Thank you for the editing! This wont really work like that, since I have to change the material when the platform moved onto a different position. Do you have any idea how can I implement the material "changer" into this part of code?: https://postimg.cc/njXLNzp8

Comment: Well... by copying more or less the same logic there I guess ? As for how to structure your code, edit your question and post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example because snippets aren't simply enough.

Comment: I think the same thing could be achieved without using `Quaternion` but simply compare the angle `Mathf.Approximately(Vector3.Angle(transform.right, Vector3.right), 0)` etc

Comment: @derHugo Yep, there are really many different possibilities when it comes to Unity!